# I dont want Spring to redirect

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Spring and Thymeleaf. In user registration form I am posting things to specific URL. In Spring I am checking if some errors occures. So if there are some errors I am adding some attributes used to show errors. Than I dont want Spring to redirect anywhere. I want him to update model and do nothing else. Is there any chance I can achieve that?

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String register(@ModelAttribute Person person, Model model){
    model = loginPageService.register(person, model);
    return "loginPage";
}
```

**Service**

```
public Model register(Person person, Model model){
    //check if user exists
    Person existingPerson = personService.findByEmail(person.getEmail());

    if(existingPerson != null){
        model.addAttribute("emailUsedError", true);
    }
    else{
        personService.save(person);
        model.addAttribute("registered", true);
    }

    return model;
}
```

**Some of html**

```html
<div id="singup">
            <p class="error" th:if="${registerError}">Wypełnij wszystkie pola!</p>
            <p class="error" th:if="${emailUsedError}">Podany email został już użyty!</p>

            <form th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${person}" method="post" onsubmit="return checkPassword(this)">
                <input type="text" id="imie" name="firstName" placeholder="Imię" onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
                       onblur="this.placeholder='Imię'" required>
                <input type="text" id="nazwisko" name="lastName" placeholder="Nazwisko" onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
                       onblur="this.placeholder='Nazwisko'" required>
                <input type="text" id="identityNumber" name="identityNumber" placeholder="Nr. indeksu" onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
                       onblur="this.placeholder='Nr. indeksu'" required>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@google.com"
                       onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='example@google.com'" required>
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Hasło" onfocus="this.placeholder=''"
                       onblur="this.placeholder='Hasło'" required>
                <input type="password" id="confirm_password" name="confirm_password"
                       placeholder="Potwierdź hasło" onfocus="this.placeholder=''" onblur="this.placeholder='Potwierdź hasło'" required>
                <input type="submit" value="Zarejestruj">
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can use a AJAX request.

Comment: Why would Spring redirect? If what you mean is that you don't want the browser to load a new page, then you need to use AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thymeleaf + Spring are creating HTML views on server side, so it need to redirect and create new HTML view with errors. You can create some API to checks if email exist and use AJAX to handle this.

If your project is small and you don't care about efficiency and security you can pass all not available email to view and try to validate this on view side (but this solution is worst solution)

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use Spring Validator

create a class Validator like below

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.med.quraa.models.User;


@Component(value = "personValidator")
public class PersonValidator implements Validator{
@Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {

        return  Person.class.isAssignableFrom(arg0);
    }

@Override
    public void validate(Object form, Errors errors) {
        Person person=(Person) form;
        Person existingPerson = personService.findByEmail(person.getEmail());
        if(existingPerson != null){
        errors.rejectValue("email","", "User already exists");}
        if(person.getIdentityNumber.isEmpty()){
        errors.rejectValue("identityNumber","", "Identifier cannot be blank");}
        //validate Other Fields
}

}
```

Later in your controller

```
@Autowired
    private PersonValidator validator;

@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String register(@ModelAttribute @Valid Person person ,BindingResult result,final Model model) {

        validator.validate(Person, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
                model.addAttribute("errorMsg",result.getAllErrors().get(0).getCode());
//you can manipulate all errors here

        return "register";
        }
        loginPageService.register(person);//you dont need to add Model as param

        return "loginPage";
    }
```